# Problema com o upload de arquivos para o servidor

Tags: php, upload, cloud

Estou aprendendo a usar um servidor *cloud* e estou tendo dificuldades com upload de arquivos.

Fiz um código com PHP e HTML simples:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="img" />
<input type="text" name="titu" placeholder="Titulo" />
<input class="lal" type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar" >    
</form>

<?php
  require_once 'conexao.php';
  if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])){

    /* IMAGEM */
    $img    = $_FILES['img'];
    $name   = $img ['name'];
    $tmp    = $img ['tmp_name'];
    $size   = $img ['size'];
    $ext    = end(explode('.',$name));      
    $pasta    = "../imagem/";
    $maxSize    = 1024 * 1024;
    $permiti    = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');         
    $titu         = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'titu');

    if(empty($titu)){echo "Informe um titulo";  
    }else{      

      $name = uniqid().'.'.$ext;
      try{    
          $stmte = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO post(TITULO, IMAGEM) VALUES (:1, :2)");
          $stmte->bindParam(":1", $titu  , PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $stmte->bindParam(":2", $name  , PDO::PARAM_STR);   
          $executa = $stmte->execute();

          if($executa){        
            echo 'Dados inseridos com Sucesso';
            $upload   = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $pasta.$name);   
          }
          else{
            echo 'Erro ao inserir os dados';
          }
        }
    catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }}}
?>
```

E o cadastro no BD está acontecendo perfeitamente, tanto que eu posso entrar no *phpMyAdmin* e vejo lá o registro recém adicionado assim como atualizando a página inicial onde as postagens são exibidas.

Porém como podem ver, estou fazendo o upload de um arquivo de imagem mas, apesar de o registro estar sendo inserido no BD com sucesso, o `move_uploaded_file` não move o arquivo temporário como deveria.

E é esse meu problema porque eu tenho exibir a postagem com a imagem, mas como esta não está sendo enviada, ela não existe.

Não entendo o porquê disso, já que se eu executar o código no meu PC, com WAMP, tanto o cadastro quanto o upload funcionam normalmente. E no servidor aparenta funcionar, já que não retorna nenhuma mensagem de erro, mas o upload não é realizado.

Não acho que seja algum código errado porque já usei esse mesmo código várias vezes em servidores compartilhados e sempre funcionou. O problema é apenas nesse servidor *cloud*.

Creio que o problema possa estar na própria configuração do *cloud*, pois, inclusive, já até alterei a permissão da pasta *imagens* pra 777 e nada.

Também alterei algumas diretivas d PHP.INI como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém saberia a causa disso?

Comment: Sao os mesmos nao. O do meu pc é Windows. O do server é linux ubuntu 10.04

Comment: evite usar <code>'</code> ou <code>/</code> aonde que você se refere?

Comment: é sim @perdeu, eu achei que tinha funcionado, mas nao funciono não. Foi só ilusão minha. Porem agora o problema está mais nítido. Da uma olhada nas barras? que barras?

Comment: Mas @perdeu troca as barras caso estejam erradas me ajudará em que? Porque no caso quando eu executo o código pelo serve ele sequer registra no BD, agora se registro Localmente ele insere as informações no BD, porem não transfere a imagem e/ou vídeo pro serve

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19189/discussion-between-perdeu-and-ivan-veloso).

Comment: Assim fica dificil, vc ta mudando a pergunta completamente, incluindo coisa que eu pus na resposta. E o pior, as coisas mais importantes que eu postei, que são os acertos dos caminhos, me parece que você não usou. PS: Eu acho bom a pessoa começar com o mais simples possível e ir melhorando a cada passo até dar problema, só nao acho legal mudar tudo depois de postado. De qualquer forma, se é pra testar, sugeriria começar do zero e testar a conexão com DB antes mesmo de ter o FORM. Depois faça o FORM sem UPLOAD, e depois ponha o UPLOAD.

Comment: A pergunta ainda tem a mesma base. o código está cadastrando tudo no banco de dados do serve porem não esta transferindo os arquivos de mídia. Minha dificuldade não está em cadastrar as coisas no BD e sim transferir os arquivos pro servidor. Esse código que adicionei ai é o mesmo de antes, só que bem mais simples, apenas com o necessário, esse é um teste pra vê se consigo transferir pro serve ao menos uma imagem! só que nem assim eu estou conseguindo.

Comment: Ivan, é que quando você incorpora na pergunta informações que estavam em uma das respostas, você invalida a resposta, no mínimo parcialmente.

Comment: @Bacco já fiz isso. Já dissequei o código todo. Já testei a conexão, as tabelas, o código de postagem sem o upload e todos esses testes deram 100%, não houve nenhum erro. Porem o problema está unicamente no envio de mídia pro servidor. Porque agora estou fazendo teste com upload e que até está cadastrando, porem a imagem que eu seleciono não vai pra pasta.

Comment: Pessoal, reformulei a pergunta. Se puderem reabrir ela eu agradeço!

Comment: Dei uma boa melhorada na redação, vamos ver se ajuda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Nota: Esta resposta foi postada antes do autor da pergunta mudar o código.
>   <sub>A **[pergunta posterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42966/)**, com base no *screenshot*, pode ser a causa do problema.</sub>

De qualquer forma, vou deixar aqui pois pode (eventualmente) ser útil pra alguém.

---

Faltou na pergunta o `form` do envio pra ver se está tudo ok.

### Ajustando o PHP para mostrar erros

Ponha estas 3 linhas no começo do seu PHP

```
   ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
   ini_set('display_errors',1);
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Mas atenção: assim que estiver tudo funcionando, lembre-se de removê-las.

É pra ficar assim o começo todo:

```
<?php
   ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
   ini_set('display_errors',1);
   error_reporting(E_ALL);

   require_once 'conexao.php'; // Cadê o caminho correto? Solução: DOCUMENT_ROOT

   if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])) {
   ⋮
```

Note que removi um `?>` e `<?php` desnecessários no `require_once`.

### Sobre as barras para separar os diretórios:

Uma das coisas é trocar as barras por `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` nestas duas linhas:

```
  $pasta   = '..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'imagens'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  ⋮
  $mppasta   = '..'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'videos'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Outra é tirar a barra destas, pois já foram definidas nas variáveis:

```
  $upload   = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $pasta.$name);
  $upload   = move_uploaded_file($mptmp, $mppasta.$mpname);
```

(ou mesmo deixar o `PATH_SEPARATOR` aqui, e tirar das variáveis)

### Melhorando os caminhos com `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`:

Melhor do que usar '..', seria o caso de por o caminho correto usando `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, assim você não teria perigo de fazer confusão com caminhos relativos.

```
  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'conexao.php';
  ⋮
  $pasta   = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'imagens'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
  ⋮
  $mppasta   = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'videos'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Esta variável do servidor costuma retornar algo parecido com isso (depende de como foi configurado o servidor, claro):

```
/var/www/NOMEDOSITE/httpdocs
```

Só cuidado de na cópia local manter a mesma estrutura de diretórios do teste.

Lembre-se de ajustar as pastas intermediárias com o caminho completo.

### Sobre as permissões:

Normalmente no servidor você vai ter que dar permissão maior nas pastas, para que ele possa gravar os arquivos. Isto pelo fato do usuário que roda o servidor *web* (Apache, etc), ser diferente do usuário que manda o FTP.

- Uma maneira seria pelo próprio programa de FTP. No FileZilla, por exemplo, você pode marcar a pasta com o mouse, e selecionar "permissões". Basta ligar o quadradinho permitindo escrita a "Grupo" e "Outros" (W/G/O).
- A outra pelo *shell* do Linux, com os comandos `chmod 777 imagens` e `chmod 777 videos` (o 777 permite todo mundo escrever na pasta, é importante saber disso e tomar os devidos cuidados).

### E mais um tira-teima pra "debugar" o código:

Supondo que você usou o DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR como recomendado acima, troque o trecho do `move_upload_file` por esse, para ver melhor onde a falha acontece:

```
if($executa){
   if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ) {
      if( !move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $pasta.$name ) ) {
         echo 'Arquivo 1 nao foi movido';
      }
   } else {
      echo 'Arquivo 1 nao veio pelo upload';
   }

   if( is_uploaded_file( $mptmp) ) {
      if( !move_uploaded_file( $mptmp, $mppasta.$mpname ) ) {
         echo 'Arquivo 2 nao foi movido';
      }
   } else {
      echo 'Arquivo 2 nao veio pelo upload';
   }
}
```

Comment: Mudei a permissão da pasta e alterei os caminhos como o você disse. Também já coloquei pra exibir os erros com o php, mas também não deu em nada. Eu mudei o código de postagem. Tornei ele mais simples só pra teste. Porem nem assim está dando. Vou alterar o código na pergunta.

Comment: levei em consideração sim. Só que como o bfavaretto disse "incorporar na pergunta informações que estavam em uma das respostas, você invalida a resposta, no mínimo parcialmente", então preferi deixar o código original. Inclusive a parte do "tira-teima pra "debugar" eu achei bastante interessante!

Comment: @ivanveloso Notar que na posterior vc nao deu o minimo retorno se funcionou ou nao pra quem te respondeu, e nem se testou o temp dir. Aquela pode ser a causa do problema, por exemplo, pois se o temp_dir nao tiver permissao, o upload não acontece (mas vai aparecer no tira teima). Você precisa entender que tem que ser muito claro ao perguntar e a testar, pois confunde até quem quer ajudar.

Comment: eu de retorno sim. Olha o 1º comentario. Eu disse que segui as suas dicas só que nada tinha dado certo! Tudo bem que não entrei em detalhes. Nao disse o que tinha acontecido. Mas sendo claro agora. Quando eu segui suas sugestões, não deu nada de diferente, pode sim ter melhorado, mas o envio da imagem pro serve continuou não acontecendo. Minhas sinceras desculpas se eu pareci desleixado com sua resposta, mas não foi minha intenção. Eu segui cada dica sua!

Comment: Tou falando da outra resposta, nao da minha. Fique sossegado que eu tou numa boa. O que eu quis dizer é que a outra pessoa na outra pergunta nao recebeu retorno (aquela pergunta que vc fez do upload_temp_dir). Eu tou tranquilo, e espero que vc consiga resolver, de qq forma. Essas coisas a gente comenta pra melhorar seu uso do site, e conviver melhor (não é "bronca", é apenas uma observação). Até dei uma editada no meu comentário na resposta, pra nao parecer tao agressivo. Tem horas que eu também "erro a mão", da mesma forma que qualquer pessoa.

Comment: Finalmente funciono. Creio que a configuração exata das barras "/" foi algo fundamental. Obrigado.

Comment: Bom que resolveu. Mas nas próximas questões, tente isolar o problema, muitas vezes você ao simplificar vai descobrir sozinho onde é que a falha acontece. Aqui tem umas dicas boas: **[Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**