# Definindo a pasta "upload_tmp_dir" de um servidor cloud

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

estou tentando fazer o upload de midia pro meu servidor com um codigo php. Ja refiz o codigo algumas vezes e creio que nao tenha absolutamente nada de errado. Pesquisei sobre o assunto e vi que minha pasta `upload_tmp_dir` está com a valor `no value`. Vale lembra que o mesmo codigo no pc funciona perfeitamente.

Tentei entao definir alguma pasta pela linha de comando, mas não consegui nada,

eu acesso o php.ini e la esta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso então definir a pasta de arquivos temporários. Porque creio que isso acabará com meu problemas

Eu ate utilizei o seguinte codigo ::

```
<?php
    $field = 'arquivo';
?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>" method="POST">
    <input name="<?php echo $field;?>" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Esse código diz que o arquivo estava na pasta /tmp/, porem o comando de fazer o upload não ta funcionado, não to conseguindo fazer o upload de nada pelo código php.

Codigo que uso pra TENTAR fazer o upload

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="img" />
<input type="text" name="titu" placeholder="Titulo" />
<input class="lal" type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar" >    
</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['cadastrar'])){

  /* IMAGEM */
  $img  = $_FILES['img'];
  $name =$img ['name'];
  $tmp  =$img ['tmp_name'];
  $size =$img ['size'];
  $ext  =end(explode('.',$name));       
  $pasta        ='imagens';
  $maxSize  =1024 * 1024;
  $permiti  =array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'); 

  $titu           = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'titu');

  if(empty($titu)){
  echo "<div style='width:500px; text-align:center;'><font style='font-weight:bold'>Preencha Todos os Campos</font></div";  
  }else{        

  $variavel = $titu;            
  //Conversao Concluida
  $urll = strtolower( preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/', "_", 
  strtr(utf8_decode(trim($variavel)), utf8_decode("áàãâéêíóôõúüñçÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÑÇ")
  ,"aaaaeeiooouuncAAAAEEIOOOUUNC")) ); 

  //Exibindo a variavel limpa, sem nenhum espaço ou caracter especial
  echo $urll;   
  $name = uniqid().'.'.$ext;
  try{

  $stmte = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO post(TITULO, IMAGEM, URL) VALUES (:1, :2, :3)");
  $stmte->bindParam(":1",  $titu  , PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmte->bindParam(":2",  $name  , PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmte->bindParam(":3", $urll  , PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $executa = $stmte->execute();

  if($executa){        
  echo 'Dados inseridos com Sucesso';
  $upload   = move_uploaded_file($tmp, $pasta.'/'.$name);

  }
  else{
  echo 'Erro ao inserir os dados';
  }
  }
  catch(PDOException $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
  }}}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente fazer o seguinte, remova o `;` do `upload_tmp_dir` e definir um valor para ele, por exemplo:

De:

```
; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
; upload_tmp_dir =
```

Para:

```
; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
upload_tmp_dir = "/tmp"
```

Comment: é. Isso ajudo definindo a pasta tmp, porem não resolveu o problema que eu estou tendo! O upload do arquivo ainda está impossível pra mim

Comment: Parece que nao funciono de 1º, mas agora começou a funcionar!! O código ta o mesmo, então creio que foi graças a isso!